# Android Gridview with different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview

How to make a GridView look something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh2h1.jpg)?
I found similar [library](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) but it is implemented using ListView and I want using RecyclerView.
Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html  may be this is what you are looking for

Comment: search on google `StaggeredGridView `

Comment: Thanks, I know a little bit about StaggeredGridLayoutManager but they add views in horizontal or vertical fashion and in my case view size is different in both horizontal and vertical

Answer (score 0):

To do this use [RecylerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mAdapter = new YourAdapter(yourParameters);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(
new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(spanCount /*in your case number of columns*/, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL /*orientation*/));
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know a little bit about StaggeredGridLayoutManager but they add views in horizontal or vertical fashion and in my case view size is different in both horizontal and vertical

Comment: @MuhammadArqam I don't know if there is `LayoutManager` that support this behaviour, but you may find third parties that do so